# Como obter o valor do attributo "lazy" do primefaces datatable no Bean?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Para obter o valor do atributo `selectionMode` do datatable (primefaces) no MB:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("IdForm:IdDataTable");
String sm = dt.getSelectionMode();
```

E como faço para obter o valor do atributo `lazy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pegar qualquer atributo de um componente JSF basta ter uma instância do tipo `UIComponent` do mesmo, que com o método `getAttributes()` retorna qualquer atributo desejado passando apenas uma chave para o `Map<String, Object>`retornado.

Para o seu problema ele poderá ser usado assim:

```
UIComponent dt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("IdForm:IdDataTable");
boolean lazy = (boolean)dt.getAttributes().get("lazy"));
```